# Solve the Initial Value Problem,

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

**Solve the initial value problem:**

$x^2 + 2xy -y^2 = (2xy - x^2 + e^y)y'$

Where $y(1)=1/2$

**Answer the question with the relation y as a function of x.**

I've been working on the following question and can't quite seem to figure out what to do. I understand that this is a Non-linear first-order ODE, and I think that it might be separable. The thing is I don't quite know how to solve this if it is separable. I thought that maybe the first step is to divide, so it becomes:

$(x^2 + 2xy -y^2)\div(2xy - x^2 + e^y) = y'$

I'm not quite sure how to get it in the following form: $dy/dx = f(x)g(y)$ (form for seperable ODE)

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2 + 2xy -y^2 = (2xy - x^2 + e^y)y'$$
$$(x^2 + 2xy -y^2)dx -(2xy - x^2 + e^y)dy=0$$
It's exact, we have: 
$$Mdx+Ndy=0 \implies \partial_y M=\partial_x N$$
You can solve this DE with exactness. Look here : [Exact Differential](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx)

---

Another way:
$$(x^2 + 2xy -y^2)dx -(2xy - x^2 + e^y)dy=0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$x^2dx + (2xydx+x^2dy) -(y^2dx +2xydy)-e^ydy=0$$
$$\frac 13dx^3 + d(x^2y) -d(y^2x)-de^y=0$$
After integration:
$$\frac 13x^3 + x^2y -y^2x-e^y=C$$
To find $C$ apply initial condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, i'm just a bit unsure about how you did the rearranging.   For example, how did $(2xydx+x^2 dy)$ become $d(x^2 y)$

Comment: Why ? what makes you unsure ? @N_Mathematics_B  Note that you can solve it with exactness as shown in the link I provided.

Comment: Im just unsure how $(2xydx+x^2 dy)$ became $d(x^2 y)$ in the rearranging process.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rearranging  Try to differentiate $x^2y$ that will help you @N_Mathematics_B

Comment: Ohhh, I understand, thanks for all the help

Comment: You are welcomed @N_Mathematics_B

Comment: Your equation is exact you should  read the link I provided in my answer. It will help you understand how we deal with this kind of equations. @N_Mathematics_B